# Is there way to join these two queries of same table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

This my table :

| name | status | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | active | paid |
| five | non active | free |
| ten | active | paid |
| one | active | paid |
| four | non active | free |
| three | active | paid |
| two | non active | free |

The output I want is this:

| status | status count | type | type count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| active | 4 | free | 3 |
| non active | 3 | paid | 4 |

Can I achieve this output Within a single query?

I can get output by querying twice, and store it separate object in Java.

For status count:

```
select status, count(status) 
from table 
group by status;
```

For type count :

```
select type, count(type) 
from table 
group by type;
```

Do I have to query twice?

Comment: It is not clear how the output arises from the input. Also presumably you don't actually want yes or no as answer. Also it is not clear what your writing after the question mark has to do with the question. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS [mre] PS Pasting 2 queries together side by side is a faq. Although this is maybe a special case of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query containing `JOIN` of two `SUBQUERIES`

```
select * from 
(select status , count(status)status_count from table group by status)table1
left join 
(select type , count(type)type_count from table group by type)table2 
on table1.status=table2.type;
```

Comment: This isn't going to work as posted. You are joining status to type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select status,
case when status='active'      then count(status)
     when status ='non-active' then count(status)
     end as status_count,
     type,
case when type='free'      then count(type)
     when type ='paid'      then count(type)
     end as type_count
from tab group by status,type
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).